# Interesting pattern in the ratio of consecutive prime numbers, does someone know the name of this pattern

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I had a thought this morning and questioned how far from prime[n] is prime[n+1]. Basically, given pn = prime[n], how much farther in terms of pn is the next prime.

If this prime is 3, and the next prime is 5, then 5 (the next prime) is 5/3's farther up the number line.  I charted it for the first million primes and this pattern shows up.

I suspect this pattern has a name, and I am just hoping someone here may know the name so I can discover more about this topic.

This was done in mathematica fyi, equation in image.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if I came to the wrong forum.. just thought this may be good place to ask such a question. I was hoping this was a easy answer, like, oh, those are _____ contours, or that's a ____ pattern.

Comment: The labels at the vertical axis are not very useful, are they? That's due to the tiny range of `ny[]` compared to their absolute values. Consider plotting `ny[x]-1` instead.

Comment: A previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980429/bands-in-ratios-of-consecutive-prime-numbers). Concerning "prime gaps" records see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first curve at the left is for the primes such that prime[n+1] = prime[n] + 2
The second one for primes such that prime[n+1] = prime[n] + 4 and so on

Here is a plot in the [1, 10000] range for the next curve :

[image: 1-10000 range]

The upper right shows us more and more distant successive primes.

Comment: The equation of the highlighted curve is $f(x):=\dfrac {x+g}x=1+\dfrac gx$ (with $g=6$) and thus the general hyperbolic aspect.

Comment: Thanks so much, I see the pattern now. Thanks for being here and helping me with this... it made my day as now I have some fun concepts to explore.

Comment: Prime Gaps ... This is the keyword I think that covers those bands. Just a summary noting what I took away as the answer. thanks again

Comment: Glad it helped @KarlEasterly: prime numbers (distribution, gaps and so on) remains a fascinating subject. Excellent continuation,